# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: How to close debug window?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

There is an annoying Window called "Debug" which i cant close. Do you know how to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Escape key. I think I've had 1 case where it was bugged and I had to restart the process to get rid of it. Might have been a different dialog though, don't remember.

Comment: Thanks that works, but after a few clicks it comes back up.

Comment: Your keyboard probably has a key stuck down or something. It shouldn't just appear randomly.

Comment: Try restarting IntelliJ. And check for newer version.

Answer (score 2):

The popup appears when you trigger [this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn4e5.png) (by a click or by a keyboard shortcut). It can be dismissed using <kbd>Esc</kbd> key or by choosing a configuration to debug and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.